# How to fix Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'Generator' in Xtext

Tags: eclipse, xtext

When running my generator configuration in `MWE2`, I am getting the following error message:

> Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType
>   'Generator'....

```
module org.xtext.example.MyDsl 
import org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.*
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.*
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.generator.*

var grammarURI = "classpath:/org/xtext/example/MyDsl.xtext"
var file.extensions = "mydsl"
var projectName = "org.xtext.example.mydsl"
var runtimeProject = "../${projectName}"

Workflow {
  bean = StandaloneSetup {
    platformUri = "${runtimeProject}/.."
  }
  component = DirectoryCleaner {
    directory = "${runtimeProject}/src-gen"
  }
  component = DirectoryCleaner {
    directory = "${runtimeProject}.ui/src-gen"
  }
  component = Generator {
    pathRtProject = runtimeProject
    pathUiProject = "${runtimeProject}.ui"
    projectNameRt = projectName
    projectNameUi = "${projectName}.ui"    
    language = {
      uri = grammarURI
      fileExtensions = file.extensions
      fragment = grammarAccess.GrammarAccessFragment {}

    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix It?

Comment: do you use maven, do you use gradle? do you use eclipse? how does your manifest look like? how does the build properties look like?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I am using eclipse IDE

Comment: Please check manifest for missing dependency